# set parameter to default loading route - ember js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have several routes in my ember project, sometimes to load some views needs time, so I added loading template with custom text, which is automatically is shown by ember while loading.

Is there any way to pass and get some parameter in the loading page?

for example in the step1 on button click action:

```
  controller.transitionToRoute('submit-invoices',data);
```

and while

> submit-invoices 
>   will load, loading template is shown.... I need to pass some parameter to loading screen.

Comment: i get this issue and on my case i try to communicate to loading component with `application` controller. and then set and observer on loading component, so when the params recive. i do the other actions

Answer (score 2):

[Loading substate route](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/)'s model hooks are ignored, but `setupController` isn't.
These steps describe how you can set a dynamic model for a loading substate route:
1. Override `setupController` of the loading substate route
2. Access the `params` of the loading substate route's parent route with `paramsFor` method.
3. Assign a model (based on the parent's params) to the loading substate controller

### Example:

**Description:**
The route `items` can get a query param `length`.
We would like to show a loading template such as:

```html
Loading {{length}} items...
Please wait
```

**Implementation:**

```js
// app/routes/items-loading.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController(controller/*, model, transition*/) {
        var itemsParams = this.paramsFor('items');
        controller.set('model', Ember.Object.create({
            numberOfItems: itemsParams.length
        }));
    }
});
```

```html
{{!-- app/templates/items-loading.hbs --}}

Loading {{model.numberOfItems}} items...
Please Wait
```

Thus, when a transition to `/items?length=10` is made, the following loading template will be rendered:

```html
Loading 10 items...
Please wait
```

**Note:** With [`Ember.Route.paramsFor`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_paramsFor) you can access the query params and the dynamic segments of any route in the current routes chain.